# Changing python interpreter for emacs

Tags: python, emacs

Emacs uses an older version of python(2.3) i have for the default python mode, is there a way for me to tell emacs to use the newer version that i have in my home directory?

btw I'm using a red hat distro and dont have root privileges.

Answer (score 17):

It is good habit to check **customize-group** of things you wanna tweak. Just do:

```
M-x customize-group RET python RET
```

you've got now multiple options of which one should be interesting:

```
Python Python Command
```

You can customize it there and Save for further sessions.

Comment: Is there a way to switch dynamically? Like I have several python projects using different interpreters. It would be nice if there is an association possible between buffer and particular interpreter via local variable or something.

Comment: @mit did you find an answer to that? I have been ferreting the internet for an answer but in vain. Although I know its quite possible through `comint` or `babel` and adding hooks, but the process seem quite convoluted and I have almost no experience in Lisp programming

Comment: This is the real answer. I just switched `python` to `python3` and all my problems were immediately solved. Also found out the switch to turn on eldoc. Thanks!

Comment: finally! Had been stumbling upon all these setq python-python-command suggestions that don't work. This is it. @sam, if it worked for you, you should accept the answer and mark it as solved

Comment: on my other pc i had to find the "Python Shell Interpreter" line and change it

Comment: This seems to have changed in a recent (25?) version of Emacs as @Philippe noticed

Comment: @mit look up file-variables but basically add something like this at first few lines of your main script ```# -*- python-shell-interpreter: "python3" -*- ```.

Answer (score 9):

### Via .emacs:

Try to add to your `~/.emacs` file:

```
(setq python-python-command "~/your/python/bin-dir/python")
```

or

### Via the shell environment:

The python command that is run by Emacs is typically `python`, so you can try the simple approach of changing your path:

```
export PATH=~/your/python/bin-dir:$PATH
```

Comment: Doesn't work by adding to ~/.emacs.d/init.el file. Still opens the old interpreter when I say `M-x run-python'

Comment: `python-python-command` is for "loveshack python.el", which was the python mode that shipped with older emacs versions.  "Gallina python.el" is the one that's in current versions.  Use `python-shell-interpreter` instead. 
 https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs#toc2

Comment: The above didn't work for me in Emacs 27. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49805906/5986651) for more information.

Answer (score 7):

`python-python-command` is for the older "loveshack python.el".  For recent versions of Emacs, which use "gallina python.el", use the variable `python-shell-interpreter`.

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "/path/to/python")
```

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs#toc2

Comment: Or add a per-file variable: ```# -*- python-shell-interpreter: "python3" -*-```

Answer (score 3):

I know that the question is about a global python interpreter, but many can arrive here looking for the common problem of setting one python interpreter per project.

Supposing one has a virtualenv per project, a good solution is to set the python interpreter at [.dir-local.el](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html#Directory-Variables) file located at the project root.

.dir-local.el example:

```
 (
  (python-mode . (
                 (python-shell-interpreter . "~/my_project/venv/bin/python")
                 (flycheck-checker . python-pylint)
                 (flycheck-python-pylint-executable . "~/myproject/venv/bin/python")
                 (flycheck-pylintrc . "~/my_project/.pylintrc")
                  )
   )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, I had two versions of Python installed:

1. v3.5 installed under `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin`
2. v3.6 installed under `C:\Program Files\Python36\`

Emacs was using v3.5 but I preferred for it to use v3.6. Therefore, I did the following to correct this by editing my [Environment Variables](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/how-do-i-set-path-and-other-environment-variables/284351#284351):

1. Start -> Type in "environment variables"
2. Select `Edit the system environment variables` -> `Environment Variables...`
3. Under `System variables`, select `Path` variable -> `Edit...` -> `New`
4. Add the path to your desired Python directory
5. Click `Move up` to place the new filepath above whatever the other Python directory.

In my case for #4 & #5 above, I added  `C:\Program Files\Python36\` (v3.6 directory) and then moved it above `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin` (v3.5 directory)