# running a different python version in emacs run-python

Tags: python, emacs, anaconda

When I do `M-x run-python' it opens an interpreter but it is python 2.7.

I would like the command `M-x run-python' to open it as is in my anaconda3 installation. I want to do this, as none of my packages are importable currently. So I followed advice from ["this answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2515952/5986651) and added the following to my /.emacs.d/init.el file.

```
(setq python-python-command "/home/eghx/anaconda3/bin/python")
```

It doesn't work. I only end up opening python 2.7

Furthermore, anaconda's python works with spyder (IDE), works in my terminal and everywhere else except by default with emacs.

As you can tell I am a noob and would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks

### Specs

Ubuntu 16 recent install, Emacs 27.0.5, Anaconda 3

Comment: What is `$` in your code? That probably shouldn't be in your Emacs config.

Comment: Also, Emacs 27.0.5 doesn't exist. The latest release is currently Emacs 25.3, and there are pretests for Emacs 26.1.

Comment: `python-python-command` is for "loveshack python.el", which was the python mode that shipped with older emacs versions.  "Gallina python.el" is the one that's in current versions.  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs#toc2

Comment: @Chris edited the $ out. Sorry, my bad. @Chris, this is the output of `emacs --version` 'GNU Emacs 27.0.50'. I used [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598985/how-to-upgrade-to-the-latest-emacs) to install the latest version  of emacs. @jpkotta that was it. I didn't know that. Thank You for the python emacs wiki. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the path to Python3 or better to IPython3 in the shell:

```
$ which python3
```

add the path to init file:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "/path/to/ipython3")
```